# Animate a div with jQuery and set restrictions

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I'm trying to do a scrollable container using external buttons, without using a plugin. I have a container called #feed with a fixed width and height, and overflow hidden. Inside that I have #feed-inner, which is 560px tall. There are up and down arrows which move #feed-inner up and down, but I need to restrict the animation so #feed-inner can't be moved passed 0 or the max height (560px).

```
$('#arrow-next').click(function() {
  $('#feed-inner').animate({
    top: '-=70'
  }, 500, function() {
  });
});
$('#arrow-prev').click(function() {
  $('#feed-inner').animate({
    top: '+=70'
  }, 500, function() {
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the value of the current position of `#feed-inner` relative to `#feed` by using [$.position](http://api.jquery.com/position/). With that you can check to see if the position is at 0 or the max height of 560px. The code would look something like this:

```
$('#arrow-next').click(function() {
  $('#feed-inner').animate({
    top: parseInt($('#feed-inner').position().top) == 0 ? '0' : '-=70'
  }, 500, function() {
  });
});
$('#arrow-prev').click(function() {
  $('#feed-inner').animate({
    top: parseInt($('#feed-inner').position().top) == 560 ? '560' : '+=70'
  }, 500, function() {
  });
});
```

Note that `#arrow-next` would be bringing `#feed-inner` upward (making it appear like the content is scrolling downwards) which seems contrary to the label "next" and vice versa for `#arrow-prev`.

One additional note is that when the position of `#feed-inner` reaches `560px`, there will be a blank canvas since the element has moved completely to the bottom and what you will see is an empty `#feed` container. To avoid this, you would want to calculate the height of the `#feed` container and ensure that `#feed-inner` does not move passed 560 - `$(#feed).outerHeight();`

Comment: Awesome, thank you! This didn't quite work as I had hoped out of the box, but I was able to make a couple minor changes to perfect it. Basically just swapped the top directions, and changed the height to -490 (as it was scrolling up, not down), so the last item stays in view.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just need some conditional statements within your click functions, no?

```
if($('#feed-inner').position().top >= 70){
```

Will check to see if the top distance is greater than or equal to 70.

I don't know if your max-height value is dynamic.

```
if($('#feed-inner').position().top <= $('#feed-inner').css('maxHeight').split('px')[0]){
```

Will check to see if the top distance is less than the maxheight.

Unfortunately, maxHeight isn't accessible as a raw integer, so we have to split the string on the `px` and grab the first set of the array to get the raw integer.